# ENDER 3 PRO - Install Dual-Z - Endstops trigger OK, but don't stop the stepper

Tags: creality-ender-3

While waiting for BTT technical support to reply to my email, I thought I would ask this community for help.

I own an Ender 3 Pro, upgraded 2 years ago with BTT SKR Mini E3 V2.0 + TFT35 E3 V3.0. Firmware MARLIN BUGFIX-2.0.x of 23/03/2020. (no change).

Everything OK, a significant upgrade from stock hardware.

Today I installed the second Z-axis (with its stepper motor), connecting it to the output (ZBM) of the motherboard.

The Stepper works fine, but all the limit switches (x, y, z) don't stop the stepper.

The end stops responding correctly to `M119` ('open' state), when pressed manually they change to the 'triggered' state. But they don't stop the relative axis stepper motor when I perform (i.e.) a homing.

Can you suggest me a solution?

Comment: Hi Jo and welcome to SE.3DP!  :-)

Answer (score 1):

I performed a factory reset and the end-stop situation has normalized.